How to cast interfaces to derived type with generics
I have a Dictionary<System.Type,IEntityTable>
IEntity is an interface used to store my actual class EntityTable<T> for polymorphism.
I need to serialize this dictionary, so i need to loop through each entry and cast IEntity to EntityTable<T>. The T is defined by they key System.Type.
So the logical idea is like this:
foreach(var kvp in dictionary){

   //convert kvp.key to KEY as actual type
   EntityTable<KEY> table = kvp.Value as EntityTable<KEY>

   serializedData.Add(table.Serialize());
}

I presume i have to use reflection ? But i am not sure how i actually do it.

Why do you need to cast to a typed EntityTable? If the IEntity can expose the .Serialize() you could simply call it directly on the interface

That would require me to edit the script for them, but it's from an API i didn't make so if i edit that script to add that function, i would not be able to update to future versions if that API has any updates my edits will be lost. So i am having to do it from the outside using reflection to access what i need. EntityTable does not have a Serialize method, i had to make that as an extension method.

Can you show the extension method? I'd like to know how you deal with T in it.

You can't, other than by doing if/else. Many people starting out, myself included, don't understand the difference between a Type object and a data type. A Type object gives you information about a type at run time. That's of no real use when it comes to casting because casting requires you to know the data type at compile time. The Type class is useful for Reflection but it doesn't have anything to do with casting directly. All you can do is check for each of the types of interest individually and cast as that type, so type-specific conditional code.

@WDUK you can make extension methods on interfaces, would that help?

What type of serialization are you using? Most common libraries can handle both polymorphic types as well as generics. But you often need to provide some kind of annotation for it to work. See for example System.Text.Json.

From the comments it looks like you have something like this going on:
public interface IEntity {

}
public class EntityTable<T> : IEntity {
    public T _field;

    public EntityTable(T field) {
        _field = field;
    }
}

public static class Extensions {

    // assuming serialization is in string just for the example
    public static string Serialize<T>(this EntityTable<T> instance) {
        return $"{typeof(T)}: {instance._field.ToString()}";
    }
}

So, I think we can use reflection to construct MethodInfo instances with specific type and invoke them dynamically like this:
Dictionary<Type, IEntity> dict = new Dictionary<Type, IEntity>();
dict.Add(typeof(int), new EntityTable<int>(42));
dict.Add(typeof(string), new EntityTable<string>("foo"));

var serializedData = new List<string>();

Type extensionsType = typeof(Extensions);
MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = extensionsType.GetMethod("Serialize",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

foreach (var kvp in dict) {

    //convert kvp.key to KEY as actual type
    MethodInfo constructedMethod = genericMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(kvp.Key);
    var serialization = (string)constructedMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { kvp.Value });
    serializedData.Add(serialization);
}

// Test
foreach (var element in serializedData) {
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
// System.Int32: 42
// System.String: foo


"These invocations are very slow," did you benchmark it ?

@Pac0 thanks for the comment. I removed the text as in our case we would do Delegate.DynamicInvoke which is indeed slower - as seen in the benchmarks in this answer

interesting, thanks for the link!
